# 24Hours for events in monthview fullcalendar

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

In week and day view im getting the time in 24H for the events, but on monthview it showed as AM/PM, so a event in week/day view is showed 22:00 and on/in monthview it showed 10p "Eventname", how do i changes that !?
I have this in my script.

22:00 is showed as 10p

```
timeFormat: { agenda: 'H:mm{ - HH:mm}' }, dragOpacity: { agenda: 0.5 }, minTime: 0,
```

and if i use this

```
timeFormat: { '': 'HH:mm' }, isRTL: false,
```

Then its right on monthview with 22:00 but then its showing the time in week/day view as 10:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want 24h in all cases? Try: `timeFormat: 'HH:mm{-HH:mm}'`

Comment: yes on Monthview i just want HH:MM and on week/dayview i want HH:MM - HH:MM.

Comment: In `eventRender: function(calev, elt, view)` you could check for view month, and modify `elt.find(".fc-event-title")` to get rid of the end date...

Comment: I meant `.fc-event-time`, sorry.